# Is there a nicer/more elegant way to do a gcc -D command conditionally in a Makefile?

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

So I'm writing some C files that utilize the classic pattern of doing this sort of business:

```
    #ifdef DEBUG
    SHOW("debugging");
    #endif
```

And also I'm utilizing the -D command of gcc, that lets you define a constant, so that I can turn these on and off via command line args.

Here is a makefile I've written, that makes it so if I want to debug, I can simply do "make d=true", and it will conditionally define DEBUG for me:

```
#DEBUG: make d=true
VPATH = src

ifeq ($(d),true)
debug = -DDEBUG
endif

flags = -Wall -Werror -g $(debug) 

mealplan: items.o mealplan.h
    gcc $(flags) -o mealplan mealplan.c items.o
items.o: items.c items.h
    gcc $(flags) -c src/items.c
clean:
    rm mealplan items.o
```

Don't get me wrong, it works 100% as I intended it to. But it looks a bit barbaric to me, is there a cleaner/shorter/more idiomatic way to achieve this conditional setting of the DEBUG define via make?

So I tried this because I read in the make documentation a few facts:

- You can pass in custom variables by doing "var=value"
- An undefined variable just has the value of empty string
- You can do conditionals with "ifeq"

So I kind of just slapped this together and it works but I feel like a better solution exists.

Comment: If I think 'no debug' is the default mode, I'd define `DEBUG =` in the `makefile` and then use `make DEBUG=-DDEBUG` on the command line to override the default.  Conversely, if 'debug' is the default mode, I'd define `DEBUG = -DDEBUG` in the `makefile` and then use `make DEBUG=` on the command line to override the default.  You're doing much the same, except you've got an extra variable involved, which seems like an unnecessary complication to me.

Comment: I agree with the above.  You should add `.PHONY: clean` and use the variable CFLAGS instead of flags and just use the implicit build rules instead of specifying it (i.e. delete the gcc lines).

Comment: The implicit dependency on a changing variables is a bit iffy as it breaks incremental builds.  I.e. to switch between release and debug build you have to do `make clean` first.  You could move that info to a config.h and then make that dependency explicit.  You could also make release and debug targets (witn target specific variables) and write to separate build directories.

Comment: Those hideous mazes of `ifdefs` are more barbaric than a extra variable. :)

Comment: I don't agree with the idea that you should ask the user to run `make DEBUG=-DDEBUG` or even `make DEBUG=` to switch back and forth.  That's just asking for typos etc.  Plus what if you need extra options (for example you want to have `-O` only for non-debug builds, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use target-specific variables:

```
VPATH = src

flags = -Wall -Werror -g $(debug) 

mealplan: items.o mealplan.h
        gcc $(flags) -o mealplan mealplan.c items.o
items.o: items.c items.h
        gcc $(flags) -c src/items.c
clean:
        rm mealplan items.o

.PHONY: debug
debug: mealplan
debug: debug = -DDEBUG
```

Now if you run `make` it will build without the debug options and if you run `make debug` it will build with the debug options.

Or, to rewrite your makefile to be more idiomatic:

```
VPATH = src

CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -Werror -g $(debug)

mealplan: mealplan.o items.o

mealplan.o: mealplan.c mealplan.h
items.o: items.c items.h

clean:
        rm mealplan items.o

.PHONY: debug
debug: mealplan
debug: debug = -DDEBUG
```

Just to note this is really not a great way to handle things.  It's far too easy to forget to do a clean between the build of debug and non-debug and now you have a mix of some objects compiled with debugging and some without.  A more reliable way to do it is write your makefile to put the debug output files in one directory and the non-debug output files in a different directory.